# Getting all values for a certain key in a python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list in Python which contains a "nested" dictionary in it. So my list looks like follows:

```
List = [{'entry' : {'Name' : 'Smith', 'Age' : 25}}, {'entry' : {'Name' : 'Mary', 'Age' : 28}}]
```

I would like to return all the values of the key 'Name' from my list without using a loop. So if I use a loop it works since this works for single entries of the list. For example: `List[0]['entry']['Name']` works and returns 'Smith'. However, I need something like `List[:]['entry']['Name']` which should return a List with the entries 'Smith' and 'Mary' in it. Is this possible?

Comment: You say you don't want to use a for-loop or list comprehension for performance reasons, because your data has "millions" of entries. How many millions -- 1, 10, 100? If the answer is 1 million, that iteration takes about 0.13 seconds on my basic desktop machine. If your answer is 10 million or 100 million, I suggest that you need a different strategy altogether -- one where the data is not necessarily held in memory and where the data is stored in way that your primary queries can be answered rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had posted the `reduce()` method as a curiosity, but since the answer was accepted, I'm posting the `timeit` results, to compare the performance with the other answers on this ticket.

```
from timeit import timeit
import functools

def _reduce_py2(the_list):

    return reduce(lambda l, src: l.append(src['entry']['Name']) or l, the_list, [])

def _reduce_py3(the_list):

    return functools.reduce(lambda l, src: l.append(src['entry']['Name']) or l, the_list, [])

def _map_py2(the_list):

    return map(lambda d: d['entry']['Name'], the_list)

def _map_py3(the_list):

    return [i for i in map(lambda d: d['entry']['Name'], the_list)]

def _list(the_list):

    return [d['entry']['Name'] for d in the_list]

the_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    the_list += [{'entry' : {'Name' : 'Smith%s' % i, 'Age' : i}}]


reps = 1000

# Compare timings

print('Reduce:              ', timeit('c(the_list)', 'from __main__ import _reduce_py2 as c, the_list', number=reps))
print('Map:                 ', timeit('c(the_list)', 'from __main__ import _map_py2 as c, the_list', number=reps))
print('List comprehension:  ', timeit('c(the_list)', 'from __main__ import _list as c, the_list', number=reps))
```

Results:

```
Py 2
Reduce:               0.2090609073638916
Map:                  0.136185884475708
List comprehension:   0.07403087615966797

Py 3
Reduce:               0.20160907896934077
Map:                  0.17127344600157812
List comprehension:   0.06799810699885711
```

Conclusion, `list comprehension` is the fastest method. `map` on python 3 returns a generator, though.

Comment: Love the timeits.

Answer (score 6):

You may use [*lambda expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
>>> map(lambda d: d['entry']['Name'], List)
['Smith', 'Mary']
```

Even though you do not see loop over here, but internally `map()` also iterates over the list. You can not skip iterating over the list in order to achieve what you want.

Better way will be to use *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> [d['entry']['Name'] for d in List]
['Smith', 'Mary']
```

OR, if there is a possibility of any key missing in the nested dict, you may add filter as:

```
>>> [d['entry']['Name'] for d in List if 'entry' in d and 'Name' in d['entry']]
['Smith', 'Mary']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 [o['entry']['Name'] for o in List]
```

Result: ['Smith', 'Mary']

Note that it is still loop. You can't do such thing without loop.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible in python, although it would be a very useful feature. Similar features are often available only in domain-specific query languages (for example, I think the Django ORM supports similar indexing), but not in any general purpose language I can think of.

Your best approach is

```
[item['Entry']['Name'] for item in List]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you can't use loops but would list comprehension work?  Let me know as to the reason and perhaps I could recommend something else.

```
a = [{'entry' : {'Name' : 'Smith', 'Age' : 25}}, {'entry' : {'Name' : 'Mary', 'Age' : 28}}]
b = [a[i]['entry']['Name'] for i in range(len(a))]
```

result:
b = ['Smith', 'Mary']

Comment: I don't want to use loops for performance reasons (in order to keep it quicker) since my actual list contains millions of entries.